# Too many open files: File IO in C on Windows

Tags: c, windows, io

I have the following code which is just printing out some text and a variable to the file.  I am getting the error "Too many open files".  I'm using C on Windows in VS2010.

```
int i, count = 0;
FILE *f;
int _x, _y, _z, _x2, _y2, _z2;

for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT * WIDTH*3; i+= 3)
{
    if (buffer1[i/3] < MAGIC_VALUE)
    {
        count++;
    }

    if (buffer2[i/3] < MAGIC_VALUE)
    {
        count++;
    }
}

printf("Count = %d\n", count); // prints correctly...
f = fopen("file.abc", "w"); // f == NULL. perror gives "Too many open files"
fprintf(f, "lots\n of\n text\n");
fprintf(f, "count: %d\ntext \ntext y\ntext text text", count); 
fprintf(f, "\nend");

fclose(f);
```

I have nothing open besides visual studio when this is running.

Comment: This code just bombs, it can never give you a diagnostic like that.  Post real code.

Comment: What?  This is real code.  The only thing missing is, after f = fopen("file.abc", "w");, there is "if (f == NULL) { perror("Error:");}

Comment: ? This is currently the entirety of the writing-to-file process.

Comment: Does "file.abc" exist?  What are it's permissions?  What's errno before the fopen?

Comment: I've tried with files that do and don't exist.  Same error for both.  Not sure how to check errno, but doing perror gives back "Too many open files".

Comment: The code that you post can't possibly be anywhere near the entire source.  At the very least, there is no reference to <stdio.h>, and you haven't defined buffer1 or buffer2.  Post the smallest program that can (a) be actually compiled; and (b) demonstrate the problem.  Hans Passant has it right: post real code.

Comment: I predict that the problem is that fopen is being call repeatedly in some looping construct. Either call fclose or use logic to avoid repeatedly calling fopen.

Comment: Consider using CreateFile/WriteFile instead of fopen to get a more descriptive error code using GetLastError()

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting too many open files, this has to do -- I believe from long ago memory -- this has to do with an environment variable that controls open handles or something similar. I'm searching for your answer and will post it if I find it. This was a good question. I agree with other comments that continually calling fopen -- if that is what is happening -- would cause this problem no matter how large the environment variable setting.

### Edit:

My memory could be going back to 16-bit Windows. Mea Culpa.